# castle windsor per window root scope

Tags: castle-windsor

I would like to register some components with a per Window-root lifestyle.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

I know that I can use the BoundTo lifestyle and bind my services to the root of the window, but this lifestyle does not support dynamically resolved view models.

My view model loads some data and then creates other view models for each result dynamically via a factory.

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it myself.

I have create 4 classes:

- A WindowScope, which defines the WindowScope.Current
- A RootViewModelFactory, which creates all root view models and creates a new WindowScope for each root view model.
- A ViewModelFactory, which sets the WindowScope.Current, to the scope it was created in and then uses the container to resolve the ViewModels under this scope.
- A WindowScopeAccessor (implements IScopeAccessor), which uses the WindowScope.Current to create a LifetimeScope for each window.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be exactly what you're looking for, but I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do:

If you use the typed factory features of Windsor and your factory implements idiposable, disposing your factory will dispose all components that it created.  So if your window takes transient factory (or factories) you can dispose them in your windows dispose.

[Typed factory docs here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Comment: I know the typed factory, but I would need the factory to pass on the scope in which it was created... which it doesn't